# How to initialize the different properties of Custom UITableViewCell in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I was trying to work with custom tableview cells for the tableview in my project. Right now I have got the tableview working using the custom cell class that I have created. **I am using XIB for the cell**.

But now the problem is that I want to add a gradient layer & an extra label as properties to my cell class and I want to get them initialize. I am writing the code for these properties in the init() like

```
override init(){
//Code to initialize the properties of cell
.....
super.init()
}
```

And I have also have the required init() which is like this

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

But its not working its just giving an error at required init().

I know how to get this done in Objective-C but have no idea how to do this in swift. Please give me some pointers on how to get this done.

**EDIT** : Yeah I did try initializing the properties in the awakeFromNib() where I got error saying I can't assign to property in self. And in init(coder:) also I was unable to initialize the properties.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: if you use your cell in a storyboard or XIB you will need to properly implement `init(coder:)` with the super call etc.

Comment: Did you try awakeFromNib?

Comment: @VitaliyGozhenko Yeah I did try in awakeFromNib . There I was getting error couldn't assign itemCompleteLayer (which is one of the property of cell) in self.

Comment: @Okapi Could you please elaborate it ? Because I tried init(coder:) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong in your code. I create new project, create custom UITableViewCell via nib, and put such code, and it works fine:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.textLabel.text = "testing cells";
    self.detailTextLabel?.text = "text";
}
```

Did you register cell's nib in table view?

```
self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell");
```

Also did configure right the nib in Interface Builder? Does you change UITableViewCell class to your custom class?